# overloading signature identical methods with const keyword

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I wondered how `std::vector::begin()` or similar methods could actually be overloaded for different return types (const and non const iterators), as in 
`std::vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin();` and `std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = vect.begin();`

Because, functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded. Then I had a peek into `stl_vector.h` and found that this is possible because of one of the functions is `const`.

```
324      /**                                                                       |   
325       *  Returns a read/write iterator that points to the first                |   
326       *  element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in ordinary                |   
327       *  element order.                                                        |   
328       */                                                                       |   
329      iterator                                                                  |   
330      begin()                                                                   |   
331      { return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start); }                              |   
332                                                                                |   
333      /**                                                                       |   
334       *  Returns a read-only (constant) iterator that points to the            |   
335       *  first element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in ordinary          |   
336       *  element order.                                                        |   
337       */                                                                       |   
338      const_iterator                                                            |   
339      begin() const                                                             |   
340      { return const_iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start); }                        |   
341                                                                                |   
342      /**                                                                       |   
343       *  Returns a read/write iterator that points one past the last           |   
344       *  element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in ordinary                |   
345       *  element order.                                                        |   
346       */                                                                       |
```

Then I tried mimicking this structure in a test program, but am getting an error which puzzles me, as the logic looks identical to me:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
};


struct C
{
    A f() const {
        std::cout << "A" << "\n";
        return A();
    }
    B f() {
        std::cout << "B" << "\n";
        return B();
    }
};


int main(){
    C c;
    A x = c.f();
}
```

`error: no viable conversion from 'B' to 'A'
    A x = c.f();`

The method returning a `B` is called, why doesn't the compiler deduce from `A x` that the other method needs to be called and what is the difference between my test program and the stl_vector code?

Comment: try making c const ...

Comment: `std::vector<int>::iterator it; std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = it;` is valid.

Comment: not sure if this is your misunderstanding, but the overload is not choosen based on the return value, but based on the constness of the object. In your example `c` isnt const, thus the non-const method is called

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing an overload, but rather, a conversion between the relevant `iterator` and `const_iterator` types:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = vect.begin();
```

If `vect` is non-const, then `vect.begin()` returns a `vector<int>::iterator`, which can then be converted to `vector<int>::const_iterator`. The reverse conversion is not allowed, for const correctness reasons.

This is largely unrelated to the issue of `const` qualification of member functions, which does permit overloading.